# Get text in the URL with Regex

Tags: html, regex, url

I want to get some text in the URL as following : http://www.house-for-rent-one.com , with regex to get the "rent-one" this is what i tried so far :

```
static readonly Regex Regex = new Regex(http://www.house-for-(?<getName>[A-Z-.]+).com, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But it doesn't work for my case, as I'm new to Regex, any idea would be appreciated for me. Thanks

Comment: Please note that `.` in regex is `any character` so `www.` means "`www` followed by any character" and `.com` means "any character followed by `com`". That said, I can't confirm that it shouldn't work. [**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/aO6rB6)

Comment: Also inside a character class, `-` is a special character (and `.` is not). To escape it you need to put it at the beginning or the end: `[a-z.-]`. what do you mean, "it doesn't work"? Can you detail and edit to show more code on how you're checking the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("http://www\\.house-for-(.*?)\\.com", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```